# Can't change language without missing the site - Prestashop

Tags: prestashop-1.6

When I change language from English to Danish, some stuff goes away from site. When I go back then al work. is this normal?

I'm using Prestashop 1.6 version.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably, some modules only have content for english, and are "empty" for danish. This is a normal behaviour when you install some themes that are not prepared to install english (or other) content to other languages.
You have to configure the modules, and edit the data in danish.

Answer (score 0):

This is prestashop normal behavior. you have translate all text for danish language or if you use any others.

Answer (score 0):

So i should go in "Translations" and fill it out?